# Why file paths defined in main source set are not visible in flavors?

Tags: android, xml, android-fileprovider

I have three flavor dimensions, in the following order:

1. `payments` - with three flavors (`GooglePay`, `CreditCard` and `NoPayments`)
2. `ads` - with two flavors (`WithAds`, `WithoutAds`)
3. `api` - with two flavors (`MaxAPI29`, `DefaultAPI`)

File paths are defined in the main source set, supposedly used by all flavors. So, `main/res/xml/file_paths.xml` has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-cache-path name="update" path="." />
    <external-path name="input_files"  path="." />
    <external-path name="output_files" path="output_directory/" />
</paths>
```

File paths are used in `main/AndroidManifest.xml` in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...> 
    <application ...>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/app_fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" 
            />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

However, running the app gives the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /...
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:800)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:442)
```

In order to avoid the error, I have to copy the `file_paths.xml` file to each and every flavor that belongs to the **top priority** dimension. In my case those are `GooglePay`, `CreditCard` and `NoPayments` flavors of `payments` dimension. Everything runs fine when I do that duplication.

Note that copying the `file_paths.xml` file to some other flavor of a lower priority dimension (for example to `MaxAPI29` flavor of `api` dimension) doesn't help.

Why the file paths defined in the main source set are not visible in flavors? I am finding that as a surprise as other resources (strings for example) are visible. Am I missing something obvious? Is that expected behavior? If it is, where is it documented?

**EDIT:**

I've forgot to mention - two flavors of the top priority dimension (`CreditCard` and `NoPayments`) depend on an external library that also defines file paths. Library's `AndroidManifest.xml` has exactly the same `<provider>` block, the xml file is named the same (`file_paths.xml`) and it's content is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-cache-path name="update" path="." />
</paths>
```

That path definition isn't visible in flavors either, i.e. it needs to be copied as well. (Since it's repeated in the main source set file path definition that I quoted at the top of my question, I need to say that it ended there during my experiments and I left it there as I previously thought that that will make it visible.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the behavior change if you use a more-obscure filename? For example, instead of `file_paths.xml`, use `file_paths_from_viktor.xml`, and use `android:resource="@xml/file_paths_from_viktor` to match.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried with `file_paths_not_from_mark.xml` and the behavior was the same. But, I have updated my question with some information that was unintentionally omitted before.